# If the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is covergent.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be continuous function such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)<\infty.$ Then which of the following is true?

$a.$ The sequence $\{f(n)\}$ is bounded.

$b. f(n)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

$c.$ The series $\sum f(n)$ is convergent.

I can discard second and third and third options by taking particular function $f.$ But i don,t know the general concept. Help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you discard c?

Comment: I have seen this question a numerous times but I cannot seem to find the duplicate

Comment: then please try to solve it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider tents of height $n$ and base $1/n^3$ (starting from $n=2$).

Comment: its means all are true??

Comment: Obviously, a and b are not.

Comment: @Augustin   How a is not true??

Comment: In this example, $f(n) = n$, which is not bounded.

Comment: @Augustin BUT yours function does't gives convergent improper integral..

Comment: If you take $f(x)=x$ then integral is not convergent..

Comment: Yes it does. The integral is the sum of the areas of the triangles. Each triangle has the area $\frac{n\times \frac{1}{n^3}}{2}=\frac{1}{2n^2}$. And the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not $x$. $f(n)=n$ however

Comment: what is our function $f$ here ?

Comment: It is exactly what I wrote in my answer!

Comment: @ZacharySelk You are right ..i am confused to understand the function $f$ which  is continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Draw a picture. It should be obvious that it's continuous

Comment: @ZacharySelk    If possible can to edit more thing about the function $f$ in yours answer so that it may be helpful to me and others also...

Comment: and one more thing this example discards option a and b what about option c?